# command not found on my program while running it

Tags: node.js, linux, express, npm, visual-studio-code

how can i solve this [I just started learning nodejs and express. I currently use Linux Manjaro and I downloaded the required things from its store, but when I want to run something ***npm start*** or ***node server.js*** an error will occur and tells me ***command not found!***.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDmNt.png)?

Comment: It means the program is not in the PATH environment of the node.js process, or is not in a directory that it can read, or is not executable.

Comment: So, how could i do that? Can you provide some steps for me, cuz i am pretty new with all this linux things!

Comment: Hi, please provide the link to the guide you are following - where are the steps you're trying to reproduce?